# How to calculate Elevation,LNB skew and Azimuth Values of Satellites in android studio?

Tags: java, android

How i can calculate elevation **azimuth and LNB skew** for satellites? All of these are run time values and change when our location is changing. Can somebody help me in calculation of these values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to manually calculate or use something like this http://satellite.ihmelapsi.net

Comment: I want to use these value  in an android app. when we can select a satellite its elevation, azimuth and LNB skew values are show according to our location.